# Working with different version of Matlab Function

Tags: matlab

We have a legacy definition of a matlab function nanstd.m which is being called in a whole lot of functions.

The legacy version has definition like:

```
function y = nanstd(x, dim);
```

The above definition is stored on our local server drive "H\Util\Functions".

The newer version of matlab has a differetn definition which is:

```
function y = nanstd(fts, varargin)
```

The above translates to:

```
Y = nanstd(X,flag,dim)
```

The above is stored under "C\Program Files\Matlab".

We need both versions to be available. Is it possible that I can write a code which says something like if there are 2 arguments input use nanstd.m at "H\Util\Functions" and if there are 3 inputs use nanstd.m at "C\Program Files\Matlab".

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your legacy definition should come before the builtin version on your path, you could simply add the following to your custom nanstd so it behaves as follows:

```
function y = nanstd(x,varargin)

if nargin > 2
    wd = cd(fullfile(matlabroot,'toolbox','stats','stats'));
    y = nanstd(x,varargin{:});
    cd(wd)
    return
elseif nargin == 2
    flag = varargin{1};
end

%// ... continue custom nanstd function
```

As per [this discussion on MatlabCentral](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/50230), the only way to run a shadowed function is to change to its directory. Amazingly enough, the path favors the current directory to the current function — something that surprised me — but it's beneficial for this case. This allows you to simply modify your custom legacy nanstd function to kick out to the builtin definition.

Edit: you may want to wrap the call to the stats `nanstd` with a `try/catch` so your directory always gets restored, even in case of an error.

Comment: I just realized that older version on our server takes a vector as its input but the one on Matlab installation file takes Financial Time Series as input. Any suggestion regarding that ? Can I change a vector to some dummy financial time series. An initial Google search did not give me any answers.

Comment: Never mind, there are two definitions of nanstd in Matlab installation. One is for a regular vector and another is for time series.

Comment: @Dennis - see the documentation for [`cd`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cd.html). When you request an output and are changing directories, it returns current working directory before changing paths.

Comment: Sorry for my hasty edit. Will definitely use that in the future!

Answer (score 3):

**Recommended approach**

This is probably the way I would do it (if I didn't want to make a complete mess in the future).

Locate all old files, and replace `nanstd(` by `nanstdold(`, this can be automated in many ways.

(If you actually have variables named `nanstd` you will feel the pain of course)

Then, to be safe define your function as follows:

```
function y = nanstdold(fts, varargin)

if nargin = 2
   y = nanstd(fts,[],varargin)
else
   y = nanstd(fts,varargin)
end
```

You may need to tweak the first call to `nanstd`, but I think this line of thought should get you there.

Make sure to burn the `nanstd` function that only takes 2 input arguments, so you cannot accidentally refer to it.

Comment: This is how our group dealt with the ridiculous [set function change of 2013a](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#btobswj-1).  While a pain, it's much more robust for the future.

Answer (score 1):

**Alternate approach**

If you feel confident, you could try to design a replacement rule to automatically update all your old files without introducing a new function. Something to start with:

Find all occurences of

```
nanstd( + something+ comma that is not between {} or ()
```

And replace them with

```
nanstd( + something+ comma + flag argument + comma
```

Especially for this one you will want to back up your files first!